# GeoServer - Adding a store

Tags: geoserver

I'm new to GeoServer and I want to use as data source a geoJson file. I've create a new workspace and now I want to add a new store but I don't know what data source to choose. Which one is the appropiate data source for me?

Comment: See: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/data/stores.html GeoJSON is not an input source to Geoserver, though it can be an output source from WFS. You can use the tool ogr2ogr to convert JSON to Postgis and use that as a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your GeoJSON file to Shapefile (SHP) file format and use [Shapefile datasource](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/vector/shapefile.html)